# Avoid Fatal Duplicate Key Error on Kafka Connector Insert mode

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I use Kafka JDBC Connector to insert data to Postgres database. My issue is that I may have duplicate data from different topics (or other systems) that share the same key and I need to avoid inserting these rows if they are already exist.

Unfortunately if I use the "insert" policy on Kafka JDBC connector it fails and exits due to unrecoverable error (duplicate key). I do not want to use "upsert" mode because if the row has already been inserted by some other part of my system I do not want to overwrite it.

I am pretty sure that Postgres has an ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING clause. So
is there a way to insert data through a Kafka Connector sink only when the specified key does not exist or at least avoid failing/exiting the Connector in such cases ?

Comment: Kafka 2.0 (Confluent 5) release can handle Connect failures gracefully

Comment: I have setup Confluent  5 for my project but the problem did not go away. Can you elaborate how it can handle failures gracefully. Do I need to set some specific key/value flag on connector json file ?

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-298%3A+Error+Handling+in+Connect